# telegraf on windows - inputs.docker error in plugin cannot connect to the docker daemon

Tags: windows, windows-10, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin, telegraf-plugins

I have this configuration:

```
# Read metrics about docker containers

[[inputs.docker]]
  ## Docker Endpoint
  ##   To use TCP, set endpoint = "tcp://[ip]:[port]"
  ##   To use environment variables (ie, docker-machine), set endpoint = "ENV"
  endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```

I get this error:
"inputs.docker error in plugin cannot connect to the docker daemon"
As I understand, that shouldn't work on Windows. I don't understand why the docs still don't explain how to use it on Windows.
How do I set the endpoint correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this volume to the Telgraf container:

- //var/run/docker.sock://var/run/docker.sock